# iOS MapKit userlocation without initializing the map

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, mapkit

Is it possible to get the users current location, using MapKit or something else, without using the map?

Say I just wanted to show the user their current lat/lng, but without the map. When they move the lat/lng updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of [CoreLocation.framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html).

At this address http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html you can find some nice information on how to get the user's location or you can google "CoreLocation" and find a lot of tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'm am only just getting into iOS dev, so things like this are easy to miss. I shall check it out, in the meantime this seems to be the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

You may find my handler helpful.

https://github.com/dsdavids/TTLocationHandler